# What use does repairing cars have?

Tags: gangster-paradise

So I started playing a real-time strategy game for android called [gangster-paradise](http://www.gangsterparadiseapp.com/). This is just your everyday, do something, wait some time, do thing again, repeat, level up, do beter stuff. One of those things is GTA (grand theft auto). If you successfully steal a car you have the option to repair, sell or chop it. Now i haven't unlocked the chop-shop yet so i can only repair and sell it. Now to my surprise if you steal a car which has been damaged by (for example) 38% and you choose to repair it it would bring $500,-. Now the repair costs would have been around $140 and to sell the car without repairing would have gotten you $360, that's right, the amount you got whilst repairing the car. Hence my question. What is the use of repairing the vehicles in gangster paradise? Is this some hidden achievement or has this something to do with the chop-shop?